# Prove that a function $g$ is differentiable in 0

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continu in 0 and let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = x f(x)$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $g$ is differentiable at 0 and determine $g'(0)$.

This is an assignment for my class, but I'm having trouble finding the right argumentation. **My thoughts were the following**:

If I can prove that the function f is differentiable at 0, and I can prove that a function $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x) = x$ is differentiable at 0, then also the function $g$ is differentiable at 0?

Well, I know how to prove that the function $h$ is differentiable in 0 and what the derivative is. But how do I prove that the function $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: You can not know that $f$ is differentiable, try using the definitions of both differentiability and use the continuity of $f$.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that continuity does not imply differentiability. For example $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous at $0$ but not differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ may not be differentiable at $0$, but the theorem still holds, as
$$g'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{hf(h) - 0f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} f(h) = f(0)$$
where the last equality holds because $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to evaluate $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{(0+h)f(0+h)-0\cdot f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{hf(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} f(h).$$

Since $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, the limit exists and equals $f(0)$. Therefore, $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $g'(0) = f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$\lim \frac{g(t)- g(0)}{t}=\lim\frac{tf(t) - 0\cdot f(0)}{t}=\lim f(t)$$

Where the limit is taken as $t\to 0$